# change random seed inside for loop & generate train test split

Tags: python

I'm using python 3.7.I'm trying to split my data 10000 times into training & test set.For that I'm trying to change my random seed. I'm writing following code

```
x=np.random.randint(10000)

np.random.seed(x)

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.20) #80% training data
print(x)
```

But in train test split I'm getting error message

```
TypeError: Singleton array array(5573) cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

Can you suggest me how do I change my seed inside for loop & generate train test split? I also like to store the seed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to pass your seed value `x` to the `train_test_split` function's first array argument, which doesn't really make sense and gives that error; you should pass your design matrix there. Also [random_state](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) argument of `train_test_split` is the seed you are looking for. Therefore, you can run a for loop of 10000 and have the seeded spilts and the respective seed like so:

```
for seed in range(10_000):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                                        test_size=0.20, random_state=seed)
    # you now have access to seed and the corresponding splits here
```